# How to edit a page of information and send a request to be updated for a mod?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a database full of movie information and i would want users to be able to edit that information, but i don't want the information to get updated just yet. I would want a request to be send to a moderator to review it first before anything.

How would i go with something like this? I was thinking of making another column with the edited information so mods can check and update.

1. So a user would go to /movies/1
2. User will then see the information and notice that some of the information is outdated.
3. User clicks on a edit information button and edits the info.
4. User presses save and it's sent to a column for a mod to check.

Comment: seems like the right idea, although it'd probably better to create a new table (maybe "proposed_edits"?) than using a column in an existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will probably work if only there are only one user. In general (as was mentioned by [max pleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2981429/max-pleaner)) you should create new table with references to users table and store pending changes there.

Another approach would be using [rails tables inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). Something like this should do the thing

```
class MoviesAbstract < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Movies < MoviesAbstract
  # your code
end

class MoviesPengingChanges < MoviesAbstract
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  # ensures user won't propose two changes of one field
  validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: [:title, :desctiption]
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And when moderator approves some `users`' changes over some `movie`, `user.movies_pending_changes.where(movie: movie)` may be destroyed.